# Which office software to choose for university and day to day tasks?

Tags: macbook-pro

My daughter currently uses a Microsoft laptop for university and other day to day tasks. I'm about to buy her a Macbook Air for her 21st.

What Microsoft Office software for Mac does she need or would be best purchase?

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/mac/office-university

Comment: And do not let someone at the Apple store tell you that iWork can substitute.  It cannot at that level.

Comment: [LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org) may work as a substitute, but iWork certainly won't.

Answer (score 1):

Your Microsoft choices are listed [here](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msusa/en_US/list/Office-for-Mac/categoryID.62686000?tid=sEqT8oihu_dc&cid=5250&pcrid=20505018173&pkw=office%20for%20mac%202011&pmt=e&WT.srch=1&WT.mc_id=pointitsem_Microsoft%20US_google_5%20-%20OMac%202011&WT.term=office%20for%20mac%202011&WT.campaign=5%20-%20OMac%202011&WT.content=EqT8oihu&WT.source=google&WT.medium=cpc).

Main differences are, the online version and the fully installed on your hard drive.

Microsoft Office 365 (it is a online app), lower cost and 4 Years access.

Microsoft Office 2011 (on you hard drive)- no need to go to Internet.

Free app: [Open Office](http://www.openoffice.org/download/index.html), does almost everything Microsoft Office does.

I have the Office 2011 on my MacBook Air, it works like a charm (PowerPoint, Excel, Word), but stay away from the Outlook Email, and use the build in Apple Mail instead.

Comment: Office 365 is not an online application - it is much the same as Office 2011, with the exception that it includes updates over the lifetime of the subscription.